# Can I use dynamic sql in ASE to declare a cursor

Tags: dynamic-sql, sap-ase

I want to use dynamic sql to select the database name for a cursor.  Is this or something similar possible using sybase ASE?

```
create procedure myproc
  @dbname = varchar(20) = null as

declare mycur cursor for select @dbname..mytable

... use cursor

go
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create dynamically a temp table
something like

```
create procedure myproc (@dbname  ....)

as

exec ('SELECT ...... into tempdb..test FROM '+@dbName+'..mytable')
```

-- and then

```
DECLARE Cursor1 for tempdb..test
open cursor
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

To use dynamic sql, first create a temp table using

```
Create table #mytemptab (col1 …, col2 …)
```

Construct the dynamic sql using the following method

```
DECLARE @sqlstr VARCHAR(5000)

SELECT @sqlstr=’SELECT col1, col2 FROM ‘+@table
```

Now insert into the temp table you created (make sure it is of the same datatypes as the sql output)

```
SELECT @sqlstr= ‘Insert into #mytemptab (col1, col2 …) ‘+@sqlstr
```

Execute sql statement (to insert data into temp table)

```
EXECUTE (@sqlstr)
```

Now use the temp table in the cursor

```
DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR SELECT col1, col2 FROM #mytemptab

OPEN…

FETCH…
```

……